# How to search array of objects and prevent pushing new row if value is exist more than one Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

On click of AddMore button, I am pushing `newData` object into `oldData`, but before pushing I need to check below condition.

I want to check if `productType`, `processTechType`, `familyMake` and `lineId` columns values are exist more than once in `oldData` array, then it will throw error.

Below is my data:

```
const newData = {"processTypeId":0,"productType":"Savoury","processTechType":"Mustard","familyMake":["Jelly","Noodles"],"lineId":["R_X002_ACCESS","R_X002_BIB"],"batchSize":"4"}

const oldData = [
    {"processTypeId":0,"productType":"Savoury","processTechType":"Mustard","familyMake":["Jelly","Noodles"],"lineId":["R_X002_ACCESS","R_X002_BIB"],"batchSize":"1"},
    {"processTypeId":0,"productType":"Savoury","processTechType":"Mustard","familyMake":["Jelly","Noodles"],"lineId":["R_X002_ACCESS","R_X002_BIB"],"batchSize":"4"}
];
```

I did below code and it is perfectly working, but my code is comparing whole object with `oldData` array,
but I want to check for only 4 column of `newData` object with `oldData` array.

Can anyone help me to do this.

```
addNewType(rowdata) {
    const newData = JSON.stringify(rowdata.value);
    const oldData = JSON.stringify(this.items.value);   
    if ((oldData.split(newData).length - 1) >= 2) {
     console.log("Item exist");
    } else {
      this.isRowExist = false;
      this.addItem(this.createItem(null));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```js
addNewType(newData) {
    let isDuplicate = false;
    for(let data of this.oldData){
        if(data.productType == newData.productType ||
           data.processTechType == newData.processTechType ||
           data.familyMake == newData.familyMake ||
           data.lineId == newData.lineId){
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isDuplicate){
        // Do nothing
    }else{
        this.oldData.push(newData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead a loop you can use find method of array

Comment: @Eliseo, Can you please come with one solution...

Comment: @Zerotwelve, It is working fine but i need if length > 1, than it will show duplicate error, First time it will allow user to add., but now it is not allowing for first time also..

Answer (score 1):

Using a find (*):

```
addNewType(newData) {
    const el=this.oldData.find(data=>
           data.productType == newData.productType ||
           data.processTechType == newData.processTechType ||
           data.familyMake.join('|') == newData.familyMake.join('|')) ||
           data.lineId == newData.lineId)
   if (!el)
   {
         this.oldData.push(newData)
   }
}
```

(*) See that using an "if" is like a "normal loop". The function return "undefined" if not find, so we use the comparison `if (!el){...}`

NOTE1: when we need compare two arrays we need compare the "value" of the arrays. This is the reason I use "join" -that return an string-, so I compare the two strings.

**Update** using filter

```
addNewType(newData) {
    const elements = this.oldData.filter(data=>data.productType == newData.productType || data.processTechType == newData.processTechType || data.familyMake.join('|') == newData.familyMake.join('|') || data.lineId == newData.lineId)
    if (elements.length <= 0) {
        this.oldData.push(newData)
    } else {
// add check here in case of already existance
        console.log("already exists " + elements.length + " elements equals");
       }
}
```

NOTE2: the comparison says that if one of the properties are equal. If you need that **all** the properties was equal use `&&` instead `||`

** fixing syntax errors in second code sample

Comment: Your code is working, but i want in oldData, if same object value is present more than one, than only it will throw error. Can you please tell how we will check if same value are present one time or twice in array.?

Comment: You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Filter return an empty array or an array with all the elements fullfilled the condition). then ask about `el.length`. If >0 is founded, if is 0 is not in oldData

Comment: @PraveshSingh, just do it. See that is only replace the find for filter

Comment: your code is still it is not working properly, i want simple check only, i am sending new data on button click, i want u can search oldData array has newdata values or not, if new data values are available more than one in oldData array of object, than it throw error else allow me to replicate  form..